# How to access the raw memory of d3d model in game maker?

Tags: game-maker

I am using the d3d model creation functionality in Game Maker. I also use dlls and I want to be able to modify a 3D model (change uv values) without recreating a model. Is there a way to locate the address of the model’s memory and use pointers to directly change the values? Is this possible and how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a built-in function for this. In GameMaker: Studio and newer, you would probably use [buffer_get_address](http://docs2.yoyogames.com/source/_build/3_scripting/4_gml_reference/buffers/buffer_get_address.html) and pass the updated buffer to [vertex_buffer_create_from_buffer](http://docs2.yoyogames.com/source/_build/3_scripting/4_gml_reference/drawing/primitives/primitive%20building/vertex_create_buffer_from_buffer.html), but in GM8.x (which the question author uses) that was not yet a thing.

What follows requires a degree of determination.

First you would want to find out an address of a built-in `d3d_model_*` function. I'll use `d3d_model_clear` here since it's one of the more straightforward ones.

- In GM8.1 you would want to use `function_get_address`.
- In GM:S you would want to use [this trick I came up with](https://github.com/YellowAfterlife/function_get_address).

Despite the amount of rewriting behind the scenes, the function stayed quite alike:

- First it `CALL`s (opcode E8) a function to pull out an integer out of the only argument.
- Then it `CALL`s (E8 again) the implementation.
- The implementation goes like this:

  ```cpp
  void internal_d3d_model_clear(int index) {
    if (index >= 0 && index < internal_d3d_model_count) {
      // internal_d3d_model_array is an internal_d3d_model*
      internal_d3d_model* a_model = internal_d3d_model_array[index];
    }
  }
  ```

  which in assembly means

  ```
  TEST index, index
  <JS or JL> ...
  CMP index, internal_d3d_model_count
  JGE ...
  MOV a_model, internal_d3d_model_array // +index*4 here or in next instruction
  ```

With the function address in your hands you could either:

- Simply connect Visual Studio debugger to the game (Debug > Attach to Process), look at disassembly, and copy the fixed location of `internal_d3d_model_array` from the MOV instruction. This will not work when changing GM versions
- Use an instruction parser (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23788236/get-size-of-assembly-instructions/23843450#23843450)) to have it dynamically extract the location of `internal_d3d_model_array`  from the inner function.

Once you have that location, you can dereference the array pointer from it (`your_d3d_model_struct* d3d_model_array = (your_d3d_model_struct*)(*(int*)that_address)`) and start investigating what is stored inside each model using the memory viewer or Watches window in Visual Studio - considering the circumstances, I would guess that there is another pointer to either raw vertex buffer data or an array of structs representing diffferent primitive operations.

Comment: One question. Is the “internal_d3d_model_array” going to stay the same each time one makes a game maker program? That is to say, can one utilize that address as a constant once it is known (of course thereby being locked to that version)?

Comment: The address will remain constant for non-YYC builds made with the same version. For YYC, it may or may not be constant as the runtime is being linked dynamically against the transpiled game code. Pre-Studio builds count as non-YYC.